# Google Plus API GPPSignIn error code "Mismatched authentication"

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm trying to add the GooglePlus API into my app.

I've added the Google+ framework using CocoaPods and I've got the sign in button in my app.

The `GPPSignIn` object is set up as follows in the `viewDidLoad` function in the view controller that does the signing in...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPPSignIn *signIn;
...
self.signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
self.signIn.clientID = @"blahblahmynumber.apps.googleusercontent.com";
self.signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
self.signIn.delegate = self;

[self.signIn trySilentAuthentication];
```

Then when the sign in button is pressed...

```
- (IBAction)googleButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.signIn authenticate];
}
```

... and the delegate method...

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
{
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}
```

It all seems to work, I get pushed off to Google to sign in and confirm access to my account and then I get pushed back to the app and the console shows...

> Received error Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "Mismatched authentication" UserInfo=0x1d5cb170 {NSLocalizedDescription=Mismatched authentication} and auth object (null)

Now I'm stuck. I can't find any information on what "Mismatched Authentication" means?

BTW, all the code I've written has come from the Google developer portal and "How to" docs.

**Things I have attempted so far**

- Double and triple checked the ClientID and it is correct.
- Changed the ClientID on Google and this stops the login completely so it is not this causing the problem.
- Cleaned the project and the project folder.
- Tried changing the scopes array to all possible combinations using `kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin` and `kGTLAuthScopePlusMe`.
- Checked that my app on google is of Application Type "iOS" and it is.
- Checked the URL Types on the app but this just stops the app being pushed back after login.
- This is definitely NOT a `redirect_uri_mismatch` problem. The problem is "Mismatched Authentication" returned to the sign in delegate after signing in.

Comment: fill the same bundle identifier in google API as you are using in to run your project.

Comment: check you self.signIn.clientID = @"blahblahmynumber.apps.googleusercontent.com"; fill your clientID you get when register in google API
and also check you have create app for IOS not for website or other

Comment: redirect_url_mismatch is cause of Not matching of bundle you use to run your app and the bundle you have add in your setting.Just Clean your build/simmulator and run again,if its not work then create a new app in google api.

Comment: Deleted repeating comments and edited OP.

Comment: If its fixed then please put an answer on what you did and how it is fixed so other people can do the same.

Comment: Added my answer now, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, fix for this was easy. Delete some code.

I followed the Google Docs on how to create a sign in screen to the letter.

I added the `GPPSignInButton` and attached it to a function to run `[signIn authenticate]`.

However, this is where I went wrong. The `GPPSignInButton` has this function built in. Somehow, by making it run exactly the same function it was causing this error to appear.

The fix was simple. Just delete the action on the button. The button will look like it has no function but it actually works as the sign in button properly.

In the docs it says to use `[self.signIn authenticate];` to start the sign in process. It doesn't say that if you use the `GPPSignInButton` that it does this automagically. Grr :( Anyway, I've now fixed it by removing the code to sign in...

Hope this helps someone.