# Find if Google+ , Fb, Linked In and Twitter apps arre already present

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api

I need to add a functionality in my app wherein I can check if Linked In and Google+ app are already installed on my iPhone/iPad and then authenticate the user through it. I am doing it successfully for Facebook and Twitter. Need help for Linked-In and Google Plus.
Regards !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GPPSignIn** class signs the user in with Google.

It provides single sign-on via the Google+ app (if installed), Chrome for iOS (if installed), or Mobile Safari.

For reference, please see "Google+ Sign-In for iOS" at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in . Here is sample code to use GPPSignIn:

```
Get a reference to the GPPSignIn shared instance: GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
Set the OAuth 2.0 scopes you want to request: [signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
Call [signIn setDelegate:self];
Set up delegate method finishedWithAuth:error:.
Call handleURL on the shared instance from application:openUrl:... in your app delegate.
Call [signIn authenticate];
```

Please refer doc https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in

Also refer this link [Google Plus API GPPSignIn error code "Mismatched authentication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530007/google-plus-api-gppsignin-error-code-mismatched-authentication)